# i am trying to get JSON data and use it an android app,using volley library but it is not working even i can not find what is the wrong in my code

Tags: android, json, android-volley

// here we are calling a method call jsoneParse from  setOnClickListener method

```
private void jsonParse(){
```

//here I have inserted my Url

```
    String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/hrtn6";
```

//json objeect request

```
    final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
```

// this is the important place where we are parsing json object 
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("students");

```
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject student = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String firstname = student.getString("firstname");
                    String lastname = student.getString("lastname");
                    int age = student.getInt("age");


                    detailsText.append(firstname+" "+lastname+" "+String.valueOf(age)+"\n");
                }
            }
```

//these are all those error handlings

```
           catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

//here we are inserting our request into the request Queue

```
    mQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: I do not think there is anything wrong with json parsing. What exactly is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `request method` to `get` like this

```
final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

to This:

```
final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

Answer (score 0):

make your requestbody to string instead of null
(parameter after url)

```
final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, "", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                .....
            }

     }
```

this helps me,
may this will help you to,
happy coding